# Local record file is empty [agora.io] Swift

Tags: swift, agora.io

I am creating an audio calling application from the sample that AgoraKit has and I am trying to add a recording function to it, but I am running into a problem. My recording files are empty every time. AgoraKit creates a recording file, but it looks like it can't fill it with data.

```
func initializeAgoraEngine() {
    // Initializes the Agora engine with your app ID.
    agoraKit = AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: AppID, delegate: self)
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let audioURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("agorasdk.log")

    agoraKit.setLogFile(audioURL.path)
}

func joinChannel() {
    // Allows a user to join a channel.
    agoraKit.joinChannel(byToken: Token, channelId: "demoChannel", info: nil, uid: nil) { [unowned self] (sid, uid, elapsed) -> Void in
        // Joined channel "demoChannel"
        self.agoraKit.setEnableSpeakerphone(true)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let audioURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("audio.aac")

        let config = AgoraAudioRecordingConfiguration()
        config.filePath = audioURL.path
        config.recordingQuality = .medium
        config.recordingPosition = .mixedRecordingAndPlayback //tried other options no luck
        config.recordingSampleRate = 16000//tried 32000 and 44100
        let result = agoraKit.startAudioRecording(withConfig: config) //result always 0 according to documentation that is success
    }
}
```

After all I call stopAudioRecording() and it returns 0 as well. So according documentation everything is good, but file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out locally and it works okay for me, here's my setup, the documents directory I'm using is a little different,  but can't see why that would change anything:

`AgoraRtcEngine_iOS (3.5.0.3)`

```swift
let documentsDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(
  for: .documentDirectory,
  in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil,
  create: true
)
let baseDirectory = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(
  "Audio/", isDirectory: true
)
try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(
  atPath: baseDirectory.path,
  withIntermediateDirectories: true
)
let audioURL = baseDirectory.appendingPathComponent(
  "test.aac", isDirectory: false
)

// start recording is the same as your settings
```

I've also added these properties to Info.plist so that file browsing is a little easier:

[image: Info.plist properties]